# What is the best way to get user appdata folder location on windows?

Tags: c++

I'm writing an application for windows, and I need to find the location of the appdata folder, to save, well, appdata to it. I'm using C++. When I did some research on this, I found some answers like, for example `"getenv("APPDATA")"`. I could use that but that question was answered in like 2012 so there might be better ways to do it now in 2021. Thanks for the help!

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string appdataLocation;
    //TODO: Find appdata folder location.
    //enter code here
    std::cout << appdataLocation << '\n';
}
```

Some people have been suggesting that this is a duplicate question. That question was asked 10 years ago. There may be better ways to do it right now, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: No, the windows API doesn't move that fast, the old question is still relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Windows API alternatively:

```
    TCHAR appdata[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, 0, appdata);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha

Comment: Strange. I tried using this but running the program didn't print anything.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    std::string appdata;
    TCHAR appdata[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, 0, appdata);
    std::cout << appdata << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Okay, now when I try to compile it, it tells me that 'SHGetFolderPath was not declared in this scope.'

EDIT: Nevermind, I managed to fix it, it works. Thanks!

Comment: #include <Shlobj.h>

Answer (score 0):

There IS (and always has been) a way to fetch this using the API:

```
CoInitialize(0);
wchar_t AppDataFolder[MAX_PATH];
SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_APPDATA, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, AppDataFolder);
```

but there are few reasons to do so for APPDATA, since the environment variable is available.